# Spring data rest one to many delete child objects

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a one to many relationship between Team and Player, I am able to create a Team with the following JSON

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "MyTeam5",
    "players": [
        {
            "name": "player5"
        },
        {
            "name":"player10"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when I try to delete a child object by removing it from the list with the following JSON

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "MyTeam5",
        "players": [
            {
                "id": 2
                "name": "player5"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I get an error saying

```
"A collection with cascade=\"all-delete-orphan\" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: org.a.c.domain.user.Team.players"
```

Here is my Team and Player entity code -

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Team {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="team", cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

}

@Data
@Entity
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
    private Team team;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Jackson is able to map one to many relation perfectly when I create a new Team with bunch of players but when I update / delete the players from Team json, it fails with the same error. Is it possible that the collection is recreated which is why hibernate throws error, if so how should I fix it? Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are facing comes from the replacement of the `players` list. Hibernate needs to track which elements are removed and does this with the help of a specific list implementation (`PersistentList` as far as I remember).

The issue comes most likely when you, or something, call `setPlayers`. Effectively replacing the list with a new instance.

To fix the issue you have two possibilities:

- avoid the call to `setPlayers` by using `getPlayers.remove / add`
- or modify `setPlayers` to avoid setting a new list, but instead clearing the loaded list and add all elements from the argument list.

A quick example:

```
public void setPlayers(List list) {
    if (this.players == null) {
        this.players = list;
    } else {
        this.players.clear();
        this.players.addAll(list);
        // you might need to take care of bidirectional references here
    
}
```

Comment: Where would this code go? This question is specific to spring-data-rest, is there a spring-data-rest way to handle this situation?

Comment: This code would be the setter inside the jpa entity. I dont know any spring-data-rest specific way of this.

Comment: Does the solution ensure that no new players are created?

Comment: As far as i can tell yes. getplayers.add is still the same.

Comment: Tested the approach given by @MartinFrey and it works. I covered all the cases adding, deleting, updating and all of them are working fine. New ids are created and deleted players are removed. Thanks.

Comment: If there is a way this can be taken care automatically by Spring Data Rest that would be great. Waiting for someone to come up with such an approach.

Answer (score 0):

You may be right that the collection is being replaced.

I assume that there is a `TeamRepository` as well as a `PlayerRepository` and both are exported. That would mean that a `Team` response exposes a `players` link where you can post the URIs of the players that should be in the Team. If the player entity doesn't exist yet you create it first. That's the way Spring Data REST works.

Also keep in mind that exposing database IDs is not exactly RESTful. The ID of a resource is it's URI.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same kind of problem using spring-boot. Updating spring-boot-starter-parent from 1.4.3.RELEASE to 1.4.4.RELEASE solved the problem:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
```

Under the hood, it is updating some dependencies, one of these is spring-data-rest-webmvc. It gets updated from 2.5.6.RELEASE to 2.5.7.RELEASE:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>2.5.7.RELEASE</version>
```

This is that particular dependency update that solved my problem.

I don't know if it is a bug or a feature of spring-data-rest. This use case is really basic. But since using all these framework (spring-data-rest, spring-data-jpa) or spring-boot default stack is all about abstractions, it seems logical to me that it is somehow handled by spring-data-rest, as far as the JSON that is sent is correct and JPA entity configuration is correct. Ideally, I don't want to deal with Hibernate specificities.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PATCH og PUT?

In the case of Spring Data Rest, calling [PUT](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_put) will replace your resource completely (and as I understand, create a new, untracked collection), whereas [PATCH](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_patch) will only partially update your entity.

In your case, I'd say using PATCH is the correct call and in my experience, can sometimes fix this issue.